# UICollectionView custom FlowLayout where to specify

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, flowlayout

I want to add a UIKitDynamics effect to my collectionView (which is not managed by a normal UIViewController). I am using Storyboard.

I am using this tutorial but I am not able to integrate the code with my project: http://www.objc.io/issue-5/collection-views-and-uidynamics.html

I have created the CollectionViewFlowLayout subclass but then I don't know where to set it as custom subclass. I tried in my storyboard file but it doesn't work.

In the tutorial there is also this line that refers to this code:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
     [self.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}
```

> Notice that it’s invalidating the layout when the view first appears. That’s a consequence of not using Storyboards (the timing of the first invocation of the prepareLayout method is different when using Storyboards – or not – something they didn’t tell you in the WWDC video).

This sentence is not clear to me. What do I need to do if I am using storyboard?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you select your `UICollectionView` in your Storyboard, you should be able to change the layout to "Custom" then choose your subclass from the list.

[image]

Comment: When I do this, my collectionView doesn't work anymore. It looks it is disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Override init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) and it should solve the problem.